# d3 link static tooltip to points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a scatter plot and want to show tooltips by clicking on each point. The tooltip will disappear only when the point is deselected (clicked again). Currently, selected points will have a black border with `r=8`. Deselected points have no visible black border with `r=4.5`.

With the code below, when I deselect the points, the tooltip won't go away. How can I link the tooltip to each point? Thanks!

```
.on("click", function (d) {
    var clickTooltip = d3.select("#data_visualization").append("div").attr("class", "click_tooltip");
    if (d3.select(this).attr("r") < 8) {
        d3.select(this)
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
            .attr("r", 8);

        clickTooltip.style("opacity", 0.62);
        var clickTooltipText = "display";
        clickTooltip.html(clickTooltipText)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 20) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px");
    } else {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .style("stroke-opacity", 0);
        clickTooltip.style("opacity", 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I am posting my answer here in case anyone is interested. The idea is to add an ID to each tooltip div. Later we can use JQuery to remove by ID.

```
.on("click", function (d) {
    var pointID = "point_" + d3.select(this).attr("cx").replace(".", "_") + "_" + d3.select(this).attr("cy").replace(".", "_");
    var clickTooltip = d3.select("#data_visualization")
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("id", pointID)
                        .attr("class", "click_tooltip");
    if (d3.select(this).attr("r") < 8) {
        d3.select(this)
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
            .attr("r", 8);

        clickTooltip.style("opacity", 0.62);
        var clickTooltipText = "display";
        clickTooltip.html(clickTooltipText)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 20) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px");
    } else {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .style("stroke-opacity", 0);
        d3.select("#" + pointID).remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending a new element every time the click handler is called. Instead, create the element once and then select it:

```
var clickTooltip = d3.select("#data_visualization").append("div").attr("class", "click_tooltip");

.on("click", function (d) {
    if (d3.select(this).attr("r") < 8) {
    // etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am creating the element inside because I want to be able to select multiple points and display all tooltips for the selected points. When each point is deselected, I want the corresponding tooltip to disappear. If I create the element outside, the tooltip of previously selected point will be replaced.